# Calling db2 udf that returns an integer

Tags: db2

I have written a user defined function in db2 , it takes few arguments and return an integer. Can someone tell me how to call a db2 user defined function that returns an integer .

```
CREATE FUNCTION TEST_FUNCTION(V_DATE DATE,V_GROUP VARCHAR(20),V_FREQ 
VARCHAR(20),V_RULE VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS INTEGER
LANGUAGE SQL
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE V_ID INTEGER;
SET V_ID = (10+ COALESENCE((SELECT MAX(ID) FROM CAL_LOG WITH UR),0));
BEGIN ATOMIC
INSERT INTO CAL_RESULT(ID,P_DATE,GROUP,FREQ,RULE)
VALUES(V_ID,V-DATE,V_GROUP,V_FREQ,V_RULE);
END;
RETURN V_ID;
END;
```

There is no issue with building the function.

Can i call this function using SELECT.

Comment: Show your code and tell, what's going wrong with it.

Comment: Please edit your question as to show what you have already attempted

Comment: You can use it as any other built-in function: `select TEST_FUNCTION(...) ftom ...` or `values TEST_FUNCTION(...)`

Comment: Select TEST_FUNCTION(..) from..  what should be given in from clause?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `MODIFIES SQL DATA` clause, then such a function can only be used as the only element on the right side of an assignment statement that is within a compound SQL (compiled) statement.
See "Note 4" of [CREATE FUNCTION (SQL scalar, table, or row)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0003493.html).
This means, that you may only use it like this:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
BEGIN
  DECLARE V_RC INT;
  SET V_RC = TEST_FUNCTION(...);
END@
```